# Read IO String and return custom data type list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, io, tail-recursion

I am beginner in Haskell and I struggle with IO operations. I should get IO String from user until user send "." (point) character. I will use these inputs to transform Custom Data Type, naming Card, by parsing the String. And then I will add the Card to the list. When user types the ".", I will send whole Card List. Haskell code is below:

```
readCards :: IO [Card]
readCards = return (returnCardList [])
    where 
        returnCardList :: [Card] -> [Card]
        returnCardList acc =  do line <- getLine
                                 if line == "."
                                 then acc
                                 else returnCardList ((convertCard (line !! 0) (line !! 1)):acc)
```

`convertCard` is a function which takes two `char` and return `Card`. Also `acc` stand for accumulator for tail recursion function (It is not necessary to implement with tail recursion, I just chose it).

For example `returnCardList 'h' 'q'` gives `Card {suit=Hearts, rank=Queen}`

However above code partition gives an error:

```
 Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
 Expected type: [String]
 Actual type: IO String
```

However below code (with dummy Card List) run properly:

```
readCards :: IO [Card]
readCards = return [Card {suit=Clubs, rank=King}, Card {suit=Clubs, rank=Ace}, Card {suit=Clubs, rank=Jack}]
```

I read a lot of things but I couldn't solve it. I am really wonder what I miss.

Comment: Formatting nitpicking: <!-- language: lang-haskell --> [doesn't actually add Haskell highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267272/2751851).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
readCards :: IO [Card]
readCards = return (returnCardList [])
```

is stating that `readCards` is an IO computation that does not actually do IO. Indeed `return something` implies that no IO is being performed, and that `something` is a pure value of type `[Card]`.

This is not what you want. You need something like

```
readCards :: IO [Card]
readCards = returnCardList []
```

Consequently, the IO must be done by `returnCardList`, which must now have the type

```
returnCardList :: [Card] -> IO [Card]
                         -- ^^ we do perform IO here!
```

Your own implementation should work, roughly

```
    returnCardList acc = do 
       line <- getLine
       if line == "."
       then return acc
         -- ^^^^^^ turn the plain value into an IO computation
       else returnCardList ((convertCard (line !! 0) (line !! 1)):acc)
```

This can be rewritten as follows:

```
    returnCardList acc = do 
       line <- getLine
       case line of
          "." -> return acc
          (c1:c2:_) -> returnCardList (convertCard c1 c2 : acc)
          _ -> ... -- you should handle here the other cases (length < 2)
```

Note that you can also do without an `acc` parameter:

```
    returnCardList = do 
       line <- getLine
       case line of
          "." -> return []
          (c1:c2:_) -> (convertCard c1 c2 :) <$> returnCardList
          _ -> ... -- you should handle here the other cases (length < 2)
```